# How to determine the direction of an edge between vertexes in a Graph Database such as OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

How do we know if an edge is an out() going or in() coming in a graph database like OrientDB?  I know that edges serve as links between vertexes (which is the same as a relationship between tables in RDMS), but how do we determine the direction. For example, I have some vertexes for Lecturer and courses, here, I want to have one (1) Lecturer to many Courses i.e. one-to-many relationship. So what is the direction of the edge between a lecturer and Courses, is it in() coming to the lecturer or out() going from a lecturer I mean how do I write the query using  "select in() from lecturer" or select out() from lecturer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of an edge is purely related to the domain and does not impact the traversal performance (ie. starting from a vertex, you can traverse incoming edges with the exact same performance as outgoing edges).

The important thing is to define the edge "name" in a meaningful way, so that the edge direction is clear.

I'll try to clarify with an example

Suppose you have two vertex classes: Person and Car.
Suppose you want to create a relationship within the two, to represent ownership (ie. a Person owns a Car).

Consider these two ways to represent the relationship:

```
Person -Owns-> Car
```

and

```
Person <-BelongsTo- Car
```

As you can see, both are clear and represent the domain very well.

Of course you have infinite alternatives to choose the edge name (btw, verbs are typically a very good choice), so you could choose something like "Ownership". This would be a definitely bad choice as it would not make the direction clear, eg.

is it

```
Person -Ownership-> Car
```

or is it

```
Person <-Ownership- Car
```

Imagine having to do a query on this schema after a few months you don't use it, with tens of relationships that are not semantically clear. You see the problem...

In the end, it's just a matter of how clear the model is. It's a human problem, not a technical problem.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Undirected vs Directed edge

**Undirected:**

A -(Edge) - B

A can traverse to B, and B can traverse to A

**Pros:** Simple when working with undirected (symmetric) or bidirectional relationships.
    Example: "A friend_of B"   ⇔   "B friend_of A"

**Cons:** Does not carry directional info.

**Directed Edge**

A -(Edge) -> B

A can traverse to B, but B cannot traverse to A

**Pros:** Saves memory and correctly describes a direction-restricted relationship
    Example: "A parent_of B"   ⇏   "B parent_of A"

**Cons:** Can not traverse back from target to source.

Regarding Your Question - If it was me, I would choose undirected for your use case because most likely I would want to go both directions.

Comment: Thanks, Herk, which means it can be out()  going or in() coming edge (as bidirectional) ?

Comment: In the case of  ORM mapping like hibernate, we can clearly specify what we want in terms of bidirectional or unidirectional mapping, But here how do I know if what I'm doing is unidirectional or bidirectional?

Comment: This is definitely inaccurate: in OrientDB there are no undirected edges (there are links, but it's a completely different concept), all the edges are directed AND they can be traversed in both directions with the exact same performance.

Comment: OP - "How do we know if an edge is an out() going or in() coming in a graph database like OrientDB" The answer provided does accurately explain. Yes, not all graphs are the same but that doesn't deserve a downvote.